# Sight range, player position update

Tags: c#, synchronization, multiplayer

I'm coding a server for a multi-player RPG, and I'm currently struggling with implementing a sight range. Since some maps are rather large, I have to limit what the client sees. My approach:

If I get new coordinates from the client, I save them as the destination, together with a move start time. Once every x ms I go through all creatures in the world, and update their current position, after saving the position they were at the last time I've updated them. Basically I calculate the new position, based on move start time and speed, and write those in the current position variables, while saving the new start time. Once this update is done, I'm going through all creatures which moved, aka those who have a different position than at the last update. In a sub-loop I go through all creatures/clients again, to check if I have to notify them about a (dis)appearing creature. At the moment I'm running this update every 100ms.

This approach is working, but I have a feeling it's not the best way to do this. And I'm not sure what will happen once I have a few thousand creatures (players, monster, etc) in the world, which have to be updated and checked.

Since I weren't able to find resources about this particular problem, I'm asking here.
Is this approach okay? Will I run into problems soon? What's the standard to do this? What's the best way?

Answer (score 0):

[Eric Lippert had a really good series of posts on shadowcasting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/12/shadowcasting-in-c-part-one.aspx) that might be helpful in approaching/solving this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using [quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) to split the game world into sections based on the areas that player characters can see. Then you don't need to loop over every creature in the game all the time; you only need to loop over the ones within the section that the player character in question is located in, and any adjacent ones in case something crossed the boundary.

I haven't done this sort of coding personally myself, but I did work with someone who did this in a space combat game for which I was developing a GUI!